# Eclipse Doesn't Find Java On Snow Leopard

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I have Cocoa 64-bit Galileo Eclipse installed on snow leopard. For some reason all my java is underlined in red, even standard java library functions. When i try to add a jre it tells me "Standard VM not supported on MacOS." I've even tried installing the 1.5 java sdk and still doesn't work. I also get Unhandled Loop Exceptions. I've tried reinstalling eclipse but nothing seems to work. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Preferences->Java->Installed JREs and either edit the existing one or create a new one with **JRE Type Mac OS X VM** and path:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home
```

You're getting an error because you're trying to use the standard VM and that does not work on OS X.

Comment: When i go to Installed JREs my only options are "Execution Environment Description", "Standard 1.1.x VM" and "Standard VM". I can only pick one of those.

Comment: @TripWired, click directly on "Installed JRE", not in sub-items.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else runs into this I found the cause. It was caused by importing a java project from another environment. For some reason eclipse didn't see the jre. I deleted the project created a new Java project then added the files to that project and everything worked fine. It seems like eclipse doesn't like to update it's config files, i've noticed this even in the flex environment when i try to change a server type.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with importing a project from CVS.  The project is an Android project and the development platforms I use include both Windows XP and Ubuntu.  When I imported from CVS into Eclipse on Mac OS X 10.6 I received the same issue.

Following the steps above I updated the JRE_LIB and JRE_SRC environment variables to reflect the 1.5.0 version of Java, but still had issues

After much futzing around I determined that executing a 'Replace with latest from HEAD' resolved the issue.

I think the process is to update the environment variables and then replace with latest from HEAD.

Problem returned today... I vote to delete my post as it's obviously wrong.

Third Entry: I'm still trying to re-create the issue but it appears to be something that happens when starting Eclipse.  After more than an hour of futzing around I noticed an error on the console about some process not starting.  I restarted Eclipse and it found Java in the classpath.  I'm still trying to recreate the issue.